# Problema al recibir datos desde formulario con ajax

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

Editado: Con trim "arreglé" lo de los espacios (igual me gustaría saber por qué están llegando con espacios los valores :/ ) pero no he podido arreglar el problema con el símbolo `+`.

Formularé mi pregunta que hice anteriormente de esta manera:

Tengo una tabla y quiero editar datos para eso transformo la fila de una tabla en un formulario, luego obtengo los datos que están en ese momento en el formulario y los guardo en variables. Luego los datos que modifique el usuario los guardo en otras variables y ambas las envío por post a un php mediante ajax. Mi problema es que al recibir las variables tengo 2 problemas:

1. Tengo un campo que se llama calidad, las calidades pueden ser `F`, `F+` o `F++`. El problema es que al recibir el string recibe solo la `F` no guarda los símbolos `+` por lo que la consulta debería fallar.
2. Al recibir los datos quedan con espacios, es decir si había un dato llamado "dato" al enviarlo por post y recibirlo quedara guardado por "dato    ".

¿Alguien ha tenido un problema similar o se le ocurre como solucionarlo? de antemano muchas gracias

PHP consultas:

```
<?php

$especiee = $_POST["especiee"];
$generoo = $_POST["generoo"];
$familiaa = $_POST["familiaa"];
$calidadd = $_POST["calidadd"];
$tamañoo = $_POST["tamañoo"];
$ciudadd = $_POST["ciudadd"];
$comentarioo = $_POST["comentarioo"];
$precioo = $_POST["precioo"];
$especie = $_POST["especie"];
$genero = $_POST["genero"];
$familia = $_POST["familia"];
$calidad = $_POST["calidad"];
$tamaño = $_POST["tamaño"];
$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
$comentario = $_POST["comentario"];
$precio = $_POST["precio"];


$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','shells');


$consulta="update shell set especie='$especiee', 
genero='$generoo',familia='$familiaa',calidad='$calidadd',tamano='$tamañoo',
ciudad='$ciudadd',comentario='$comentarioo',precio='$precioo' where especie='$especie' 
and genero=$'$genero'and familia='$familia'and calidad='$calidad'and tamano='$tamaño'and 
ciudad='$ciudad'and comentario='$comentario'and precio='$precio' "

$request=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta); 

if($request) echo "funciona";
else echo "error";  

?>
```

Acá muestro los datos:

```
    <?php


        $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','shells');




        $request=mysqli_query($conexion,"select especie, genero,familia,calidad,tamano,ciudad,comentario,precio from shell where habitad='land' order by familia,genero,especie ");



        while($prueba=$request->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>


        <tr class="info">




    <td><?php echo $prueba['familia']   ;   ?>  </td> 
    <td><?php echo $prueba['genero']   ;    ?>  </td> 
    <td><?php echo $prueba['especie'] ;     ?>  </td> 

    <td><?php echo $prueba['calidad']   ;   ?>  </td> 
    <td><?php echo $prueba['tamano']   ;    ?>  </td> 
    <td><?php echo $prueba['ciudad']   ;    ?>  </td> 
    <td><?php echo $prueba['comentario'];   ?>  </td> 
    <td><?php echo $prueba['precio']   ;    ?>  </td> 

    <td><input type=submit name="editar" value="Editar" onclick="transformarEnEditable(this)" class="btn btn-primary"> </input> </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="eliminar" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger"></input></td>
        </tr>

    <?php   } ?>
```

Y aca tengo la función que me transforma la tabla en un formulario

```
function transformarEnEditable(nodo){
//El nodo recibido es SPAN
if (editando == false) {
editando = "true";

var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD
var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR

var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');
 especie = nodosEnTr[0].textContent; 
 genero = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;
 familia = nodosEnTr[2].textContent; 
 calidad = nodosEnTr[3].textContent;
 tamaño = nodosEnTr[4].textContent; 
 ciudad = nodosEnTr[5].textContent;
 comentario = nodosEnTr[6].textContent;
 precio = nodosEnTr[7].textContent;
 Editar = nodosEnTr[8].textContent;
 nuevoCodigoHtml = '<td><input type="text" name="especie" id="especie" value="'+especie+'" size="17"></td>'+
'<td><input type="text" name="genero" id="genero" value="'+genero+'" size="10"</td>'+
'<td><input type="text" name="familia" id="familia" value="'+familia+'" size="10"</td>'+
'<td><input type="text" name="calidad" id="calidad" value="'+calidad+'" size="5"</td> '+
'<td><input type="text" name="tamaño" id="tamaño" value="'+tamaño+'" size="5"</td> '+
'<td><input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="'+ciudad+'" size="10"</td> '+
'<td><input type="text" name="comentario" id ="comentario" value="'+comentario+'" size="20"</td> '+
'<td><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value="'+precio+'" size="5"</td> '+
'<td><input class="btn btn-primary" onclick=editar2()  id="boton" Value="aceptar" type="submit"></input></td>'+
'<td><input class="btn btn-danger" onclick=editar2() value="eliminar" type="submit"></input> ' ;






nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;
```

Ajax:

```
function editar2(){


    var especiee = jQuery("#especie").val();
        var generoo = jQuery("#genero").val();
        var familiaa = jQuery("#familia").val();
        var calidadd = jQuery("#calidad").val();
        var tamañoo = jQuery("#tamaño").val();
        var ciudadd = jQuery("#ciudad").val();
        var comentarioo = jQuery("#comentario").val();
        var precioo = jQuery("#precio").val();

    console.log("presionaste boton editar"); 
        console.log(calidad);



        $.ajax({

            data: "especiee=" + especiee + "&generoo=" +generoo + "&familiaa="+familiaa+ "&calidadd="+calidadd+"&tamañoo="+tamañoo+"&ciudadd="+ciudadd+
                    "&comentarioo="+comentarioo+"&precioo="+precioo+"&especie=" + especie + "&genero=" +genero + "&familia="+familia+ "&calidad="+calidad+"&tamaño="+tamaño+"&ciudad="+ciudad+
                    "&comentario="+comentario+"&precio="+precio, 
                    //envio los datos al ajax.php donde procesara la consulta
            url:   'ajax/ajax.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            type:  'post',
            beforeSend: function () {
                //mostramos gif "cargando"

                //antes de enviar la petición al fichero PHP, mostramos mensaje
                jQuery("#resultado").html("Buscando");
            },
            success:  function (response) {

                console.log(response);
                jQuery("#terrestres").html(response);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){


            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Estoy viendo si se soluciona con trim, pero por que esta recibiendo espacios en blanco?

Comment: Otro fallo que veo... no estás cerrando los inputs: `size="10"`... `size="10">`...

Comment: Chuta, gracias nuevamente, aunque lo cambie y quedo igual jaja

Comment: lo del espacio puede ser este espacio `?>  </td>`... te recomiendo que formates bien tú código... no solo por ser legible sino también por los _pequeños_ `bugs`

Comment: Si, estoy en eso ahora gracias ^^ el problema del + por que podra ser? solo me pasa con el +

Comment: Quizás te ayude esto: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode)... me voy ya (zzzz)... mañana me paso y miro a ver que tal...saludos

Comment: Te pasaste mil gracias, estoy viendo lo que me mandaste y parece que esa es la solución :D ahora lo intento y cuento como me fue ^^

Comment: ¿Podría ver el código javascript que realiza la petición Ajax? Parece que no estás tratando los datos bien en origen, en el navegador del cliente. Por otro lado, supongo que ya te habrán dicho que `trim()` te ayudará a quitar los espacios sobrantes a ambos lados de la cadena.

Comment: Como te pones el código que genera la petición Ajax te he escrito una prueba de concepto con formas que suele usar mal la gente y cómo hacerlo correctamente. Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Hola, acabo de subir el código que realiza la petición ajax, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PHP puedes limpiar los espacios en blanco a ambos lados de una cadena con la función [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim). También tienes disponibles [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/ltrim) y [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim).

En cuanto al envío del Ajax todo apunta a que los problemas los tienes en javascript de origen.

Dependiendo de cómo montes la consulta los signos `+` se convertirán en un espacio en blanco debido a que en la codificación URL el signo `+` es un carácter reservado ([ver sección 2.2 del RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)).

Si estás usando jQuery te recomiendo usar [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) para hacer el trabajo de escapar de manera correcta los datos que serán enviados.

Te pongo un ejemplo de cómo usarlo correctamente:

```js
/* Valor que queremos enviar */
var prueba = "++PRUEBA++";
/* Montando mal la petición Ajax */
$("#malo1").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo',
    dataType: 'text',
    crossOrigin: true,
    data: "body=" + prueba
  }).done(function(datos) {
    alert("Recibido (malo 1): " + datos);
  });
});
/* Montando mal los datos a enviar */
$("#malo2").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?body=' + prueba,
    dataType: 'text',
    crossOrigin: true,
  }).done(function(datos) {
    alert("Recibido (malo 2): " + datos);
  });
});
/* Permitiendo a jQuery.param() generar la cadena */
$("#bueno1").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo',
    dataType: 'text',
    crossOrigin: true,
    data: $.param({ body: prueba })
  }).done(function(datos) {
    alert("Recibido (bueno 1): " + datos);
  });
});
$("#bueno2").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo',
    dataType: 'text',
    crossOrigin: true,
    data: { body: prueba }
  }).done(function(datos) {
    alert("Recibido (bueno 2): " + datos);
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bueno1">Pulse para envío BUENO (1)</button>
<button id="bueno2">Pulse para envío BUENO (2)</button>
<button id="malo1">Pulse para envío MALO (1)</button>
<button id="malo2">Pulse para envío MALO (2)</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, estoy leyendo ahora sobre el envío de datos para entender un poco mejor ya que me enredé bastante jaja, me sirvió mucho tu respuesta, seguiré leyendo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Funciono!!!!! :D aún no entiendo por que jaja pero seguire leyendo para entender, te pasaste mil gracias :D

Comment: El funcionamiento es sencillo, si montas tú mismo la URL podrás cometer errores de codificación por el uso de caracteres reservados como `&`, `=`, `+`, etc... sin embargo `$.param` lo prepara todo escapando los caracteres en entidades. En mi ejemplo, convierte `http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?body=++PRUEBA++` en `http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?body=%2B%2BPRUEBA%2B%2B`.

Comment: al enviar por post o get  de esta manera valor:'valor' entonces no se codifican los valores? y por que había que enviar los datos en manera de un arreglo referencial (si es que eso hiciste jaja)

Comment: Por cada pareja de valores monta un "índice=valor", pero codificando la secuencia. Si hay más datos los une con un "&", pero tú puedes olvidarte de eso, se encarga la función de hacerlo por ti.

Comment: Te he puesto un ejemplo "bueno" adicional. Cuando se usa una llamada `jQuery.ajax()` no es necesario usar `$.param()`, si envías los datos directamente en el campo `data` éstos se convertirán en parámetros de manera correcta.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad. Le estoy haciendo una pagina a mi papa para que pueda organizar sus datos de un museo que esta intentando hacer funcionar. así que en nombre de los 2 muchas gracias! :D

Comment: Gracias solucionado con data: $.param({ body: prueba })

Comment: Gracias. Me alegra saber que fui de ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

El símbolo "+" en el mundo web se suele convertir en un espacio en blanco automáticamente. Para que viaje y sea significativo tendrás que codificarlo. Hay varias funciones en javascript y en PHP para ello, como encodeURIComponent, urlencode y demás. El resultado final debería ser que cualquier simbolo "+" que enviases en tu petición debería viajar codificado como "%2B".

Comment: Gracias :D ahora estoy buscando como hacerlo bien ^^